# Why am I getting this error, I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: python, function, numpy, numpy-ndarray, sampling

I am trying to define the weight of my sample because I am learning importance sampling, but for some reason it keeps showing me an error, I have defined the weight exactly in this format previously and it worked. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# Defining EP(E)
Emin = 0.511
Emax = 1.292
A = 17.661
def EP(E):
  EP = np.where((E >= Emin) & (E <= Emax), (E*A*E*(np.sqrt(E**2-Emin**2))*((Emax - E)**2)), 0 )
  return EP

# Defining Proposal Distribution 
def Q3(E):
  Q3 = np.where((E >= Emin) & (E <= Emax),(-2*np.cos(4*E)),0)
  return Q3

# Sampling fromm Q3(E)
def sample3_E(num):
  r = Emin + (Emax-Emin)*np.random.rand(num)
  E_samples3 = (1/4)*np.arcsin(r)
  return E_samples3

# Finding weights
num = 100000
def weight3(E_samples3):
  w3 = P(E_samples3)/Q3(E_samples)
  return w3

E_samples3 = sample3_E(num)
w3 = weight3(E_samples)

Q3 = Q3(E)
EP = EP(E)
plt.hist(E_samples3,bins=50,alpha=0.5,weights=w3,density=True,label='Weighted samples')
plt.plot(E,EP, label = 'EP(E)', color = 'blue')
plt.plot(E,P, label = 'P(E)', color = 'darkorange')
plt.plot(E,Q3, label = 'Q3(E)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-5625fe2909b6> in <module>()
     28 
     29 E_samples3 = sample3_E(num)
---> 30 w3 = weight3(E_samples)
     31 
     32 Q3 = Q3(E)

<ipython-input-160-5625fe2909b6> in weight3(E_samples3)
     24 num = 100000
     25 def weight3(E_samples3):
---> 26   w3 = P(E_samples3)/Q3(E_samples)
     27   return w3
     28 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: A line like `Q3 = Q3(E)` replaces the Q3 function name with the return value of the function, so the function Q3 no longer exists.

Comment: what is E ??????